# Google Big Query splitting an ingestion time partitioned table

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have an ingestion time partitioned table that's getting a little large. I wanted to group by the values in one of the columns and use that to split it into multiple tables. Is there an easy way to do that while retaining the original _PARTITIONTIME values in the set of new ingestion time partitioned tables?

Also I'm hoping for something that's relatively simple/cheap. I could do something like copy my table a bunch of times and then delete the data for all but one value on each copy, but I'd get charged a huge amount for all those DELETE operations.

Also I have enough unique values in the column I want to split on that saving a "WHERE column = value" query result to a table for every value would be cost prohibitive. I'm not finding any documentation that mentions whether this approach would even preserve the partitions, so even if it weren't cost prohibitive it may not work.

Comment: what's a _"little large"_?

Comment: 30 TB. The exact size shouldn't affect the splitting process though should it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case you describe required having two level partitioning which is not supported yet

You can create column partition table https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-column-partitions
And after this build this value of column as needed that used to partitioning before insert - but in this case you lost _PARTITIONTIME value

Based on additional clarification - I had similar problem - and my solution was to write python application that will read source table (read is important here - not query - so it will be free) - split data based on your criteria and stream data (simple - but not free) or generate json/csv files and upload it into target tables (which also will be free but with some limitation on number of these operations) - will required more coding/exception handling if you go second route.

You can also can do it via DataFlow - it will be definitely more expensive than custom solution but potentially more robust.

Examples for gcloud python library

```
client = bigquery.Client(project="PROJECT_NAME")

t1 = client.get_table(source_table_ref)
target_schema = t1.schema[1:] #removing first column which is a key to split
ds_target = client.dataset(project=target_project, dataset_id=target_dataset)

rows_to_process_iter = client.list_rows( t1, start_index=start_index, max_results=max_results)
# convert to list
rows_to_process = list(rows_to_process_iter)
# doing something with records

# stream records to destination 
errors = client.create_rows(target_table, records_to_stream)
```

Comment: A two level partitioned table would be pretty much equivalent, but I'd prefer separate tables - makes a $150 mistake harder to make. I didn't understand your next statement. I think you're talking about making a table with user specified partitions. This is possible, but I'd prefer to keep my table ingestion time partitioned. I'll edit my question to make this clearer.

Comment: What tool did you use to read the table? Is it capable of reading a selection of partitions or do I need to read the whole table?

Comment: It is tabledata list API https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/list or client.list_rows() function in gcloud python library

Comment: Alright thanks. It looks like I can query each partition for COUNT(*), read that number of rows with that tool, then split and upload. I'll have to run the script over a couple days to avoid limits, but it should be free or at least cheap.

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery now supports *[clustered](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/clustered-tables)* partitioned tables, which allow you to specify additional columns that the data should be split by.